# should a java library be autowired?

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, code-injection

One of the features for Java Spring is dependecy injection. When you write seperate classes that are instiantiated into another class as a dependecy its good practice to use @Autowired and @Component instead of using new. Should the variable counter be @Autowired and returned by another class? Below is the example class for @Component. Here is some info on dep inj: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm

```
@Component
class CounterClass {
    private final AtomicLong counter;

    public CounterClass() {
        this.counter = new AtomicLong();
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.restservice;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    //should counter be @Autowired??
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the use case for the counter in more detail? It's not usual to keep mutable state like this inside a service (for many reasons, including that you usually have multiple copies of your application running on separate servers), so the specific use of the counter is important. If you're wanting metrics, there's a dedicated system for that (Micrometer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject anything that you *might* want to substitute, e.g. during unit testing.

In this case, would you possibly want to use an `AtomicLong` that doesn't start at 0, when testing? If yes, then you need to be able to *inject* a non-default instance.

Comment: If that's the case, then the `AtomicLong` is probably the wrong abstraction to be using here.